# Switched from 18.04 to 20.04 cannot use Desktop icons normally

Tags: 20.04, desktop-icons

So I've switched from 18.04 to 20.04, I copied my whole user data and recopied them back to 20.04. So that includes desktop as well, but now I cannot double click to open files, cannot move files to the Desktop from other folders, the Desktop reorganizes itself weirdly and stuff like that. I just installed the fresh 20.04 LTS.

Answer (score -1):

Check you're the owner of all files under user data. Try this:

```
user@host:~$ ls -laR | less
```

if you see *uid* or *gid* differents from *user*, I think that's the problem. Try this

```
chown -R user.user *
```

Of course you have to change *user* with your user name in the exemple above